# Godep with local packages

Tags: git, go, godeps

I have a repository that looks like this:

```
src
|
|--myplace
   |--myprojectRepo
      |--someCmd
      |      main.go
      |--somePackage
      |      package.go
```

I'm trying to use Godeps to manage dependencies.  However, when I run `godep save` inside of the `someCmd` folder, it copies not just the external code into the godep `_workspace`, but also the `somePackage` code into the godep `_workspace`.

Is there anyway to stop godep from copying code that is in the same repository into its `_workspace`?

The main ugliness that I see with this is that now there are  two versions of `somePackage.go`. One in the `somePackage` directory and one in the `godeps/_workspace...` directory.  And if I make a change to `somePackage`, I have to rerun godep inside of `someCmd` in order to have those changes pulled in.

Comment: My import is uses the full path `myplace/myprojectRepo/somePackage`.  There are no errors, it just was odd to me that a folder in my repository contained the contents of another folder.

Comment: oh sorry, I completely misread what you were saying. You want to *stop* godep from doing that! There's probably no way, since godep uses the VCS to manage the files. If you clone `myprojectRepo`, you're going to get all the files it contains.

Comment: I'm OK with getting all the files it contains, but with godeps, when I check out `myprojectRepo`, it has two versions of `somePackage.go`.  One in the somePackage directory and one in the `godeps/_workspace...`directory.

Comment: You should run godep from `src` directory

Answer (score 0):

> when I run godep save inside of the someCmd folder

Godep will vendor everything that is not a **sub-directory**, it does not goes up to your repository's root.

You have to run `godep save ./...` from the root of your project : it will save all external dependencies for your project in one place.

As @JimB said, anyway people are gonna be pulling the whole repository at once, not sub-packages by sub-packages. And they should run `godep restore` from the repository's root too.