# Godep processing custom packages

Tags: heroku, go, godeps

Here's my problem.
I have go-app which uses some custom packages I created by myself. 
I don't want to publish this packages on git or elsewhere. 
They're just packages with some certain functionality.

So, my project folder looks like this:

```
|--src/github/u-mulder
  |--/project_name
       |--/Godeps  
       |--/public
       |--/vendor
       |--main.go  
       |--Procfile
```

I place my packages to `vendor` folder:

```
-/Godeps  
-/public
-/vendor
  |---/github.com/u-mulder/package_one/package_one.go
  |---/github.com/u-mulder/package_two/package_two.go
-main.go  
-Procfile
```

Okay, in my `main.go` I successfully import this packages:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/u-mulder/package_one"
    "github.com/u-mulder/package_two"
    // more packages here    
)
```

And everything works fine.

Now I want to prepare my project for deploying to heroku using `godep`.
So, in a root folder of my project I run

```
> godep save ./...
```

And here comes my problem - as my packages are already in a `vendor` folder, I receive error:

> godep: Package (github.com/u-mulder/package_one) not found

Sure, I can create a project for every of my packages. Then the structure of `src` will look like:

```
|--src/github/u-mulder
  |--/package_one
    |-package_one.go
  |--/package_two
    |-package_two.go
  |--/project_name
       |--/Godeps  
       |--/public
       |--/vendor
       |--main.go  
       |--Procfile
```

Then the above mentioned problem is gone, but the second one appears:

> godep: error while inspecting `"$GOPATH/src/github.com/u-mulder/package_one"`: directory `"$GOPATH/src/github.com/u-mulder/package_one"` is not using a known version control system

So, of course I can create a `.git` repository in each project package (and maybe this problem will be gone), but I don't want, these are just local packages for my use only.

So, the question is - where to place my custom (or say - local) packages so `godep` can find them and don't want them to be "real" packages?

Something similar I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589511/godep-with-local-packages), but it's not about `vendor` folder.

Comment: Why are you using a "github.com" path if your sources aren't on github? Even for local packages, you should be using a version control of some sort. godep can't version the package if there's no version control.

Comment: @JimB Ok, I can change path to my packages to something else (`local` or whatever) but that doesn't help. And all my project is under version control (otherwise I can't place it on heroku).

Comment: But you said in the question that you don't want to create a git repo for each package, so I'm confused as to what you're trying to do. If you've already vendored all the required packages, what is it you want godep to achieve?

Comment: Hmmm, I put my packages in `vendor` folder, manually. Then I use `godep save ./...` and get a described error `Package not found`. Also I should mention that there other packages in `vendor` (`libpq` for example) which are processed correctly.

Comment: If the packages are already in the vendor folder, then what is godep supposed to do? `godep save` records the "source control revision" of the package found in GOPATH, then copies that to the vendor folder. If the package is already in `vendor/`, and doesn't have any revision control, then there's nothing godep can do.

Comment: So I suppose that I should first run `godep` for updating/adding external dependencies (like `libpq` for example), then - manually place my packages into `vendor` and after that - commit?

Comment: Or, you could keep your dependencies in GOPATH, with version control, and just let godep handle them all.

Comment: @JimB Sure, but the case was that I want to avoid that) But anyway, thanks. Not sure what should I do with the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JimB comments I found out the following:

the most obvious and simple solution is just

> keep your dependencies in GOPATH, with version control, and just let godep handle them all (@JimB)

So yes, this means adding package(s) to git and all this stuff.

In case if you don't want/can't do that, the order of actions can be:

- Code
- Test
- Remove your local dependecies (packages) from `vendor`
- Run `godep` to update other dependecies (like `httprouter`, `libpq`, etc)
- Manually add your local dependecies back to `vendor`
- Commit

But obvioulsy it is **not** a good way.